# what is wrong with my simple sqlxml query?

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xquery

Sorry,

Been struggle with this query for a while

```
declare @a xml
select @a='<GrsAutoCompleteCodes>
  <GrsAutoCompleteCode CitiCode="00DX" IsMatched="0" HasCustomName="0" />
  <GrsAutoCompleteCode CitiCode="00G0" IsMatched="0" HasCustomName="0" />
</GrsAutoCompleteCodes>'

SELECT       
 p.s.value('(CitiCode/text())[1]','VARCHAR(100)') AS CitiCode
FROM @a.nodes('/GrsAutoCompleteCode') p(s)
```

This query somehow returns no records, what am I doing wrongly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it's completely wrong, I'm afraid. Your root is `GrsAutoCompleteCodes` not `GrsAutoCompleteCode`, and `CitiCode` isn't a node it's a property of `GrsAutoCompleteCode`.

Perhaps you want this, which returns the value of `CitiCode` for the first `GrsAutoCompleteCode` node:

```sql
DECLARE @a xml;
SET @a = '<GrsAutoCompleteCodes>
  <GrsAutoCompleteCode CitiCode="00DX" IsMatched="0" HasCustomName="0" />
  <GrsAutoCompleteCode CitiCode="00G0" IsMatched="0" HasCustomName="0" />
</GrsAutoCompleteCodes>'

SELECT a.GACC.value('(GrsAutoCompleteCode/@CitiCode)[1]','varchar(4)') AS CitiCode
FROM @a.nodes('/GrsAutoCompleteCodes')a(GACC);
```

If you want the value of every `CitiCode`, that would be this:

```sql
SELECT a.GACC.value('@CitiCode','varchar(4)') AS CitiCode
FROM @a.nodes('/GrsAutoCompleteCodes/GrsAutoCompleteCode')a(GACC);
```